# Local push notification in mac app

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa, notifications

I want to implement local push notification like iOS app in MAC app. Similar in iCal.

Is it possible to implement when application not running and how?

If not possible, then I don't want to use NSTimer to trigger particular event.

any suggestion what would be the right way to achieve requirement.

Thanks
MD

Comment: have you looked at growl notifications

Comment: I think you should write some daemon which will be running all time. Something like iTunesHelper. As I know, Grow can only show notifications when they was sent. But there we need show notifications even if application is not running.

Answer (score 0):

Coming in Mountain Lion, I believe.

Answer (score 0):

I think something run in the background accept the notification and show it to the user. iOS will you to do it but OSX will not. Your application must be ran when a notification is arrived. In mountain lion, NSUserNotificationCenter can help you because of NotificationCenter(a process) always run on background.(1)
If you do not want to flush your notification list by NSTimer,how about use NSNotification or build a delegate for your controller,and implement some callback methods,that can notify user immediately when a notification is posted to your notification center.